# Flutter Gridview button functionality to new screen with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I've made a Gridview using Firebase and Streambuilder and Gridview.builder. This grid displays album titles, the album cover art for each album, and the artists that make each album. I'd like for each grid tile to be able to be pressed and navigate to a separate page with its specific album details. The plan was on press, the app would be able to identify the entire document the grid tile was referring to, move to a new page, and display the document in full to unveil the album details. The thing is, I don't know how to do that. Since `snapshot.data.documents[index]['Title']` worked when iterating though all the documents to create the gridview, I thought that typing `snapshot.data.documents[index]` would work, but it just displays `Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'` in the debug console. I'm out of ideas on how to tackle this, so any suggestions are welcome

**My code is shown below**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Services services = Services();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgcolour,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
        title: Text("Home"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Icon(Icons.more_vert))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('music').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
            return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 0.655172413),
              //cacheExtent: 1000.0,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var url = snapshot.data.documents[index]['Cover Art'];

                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 190.0,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
                      color: hexToColor(
                          snapshot.data.documents[index]['Palette'][0]),
                      elevation: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                          ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21.0),
                              child: Image.network(url,
                                  height: 180.0, width: 180)),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(
                              snapshot.data.documents[index]['Artist']
                                  .join(', '),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['Title'],
                              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Tapped ${snapshot.data.documents[index]}");
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an ID for your `snapshot.data.documents[index]`? If yes, add it to the end.

```
onTap: () {
     print("Tapped ${snapshot.data.documents[index]['the property you want']}");
},
```